# creating a real time connection using node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq, real-time

sorry i searched for my questions but didn't find any useful answer.

i want to create a real time connection between an android device and a raspberry pie using node js.
each android device can send message to a some specific raspberries. so i think i need to monitor each message that android device want to send to respberry and if it is not allowed i should block it's connection.
i know something about socket.io and i think i can use it to do this.
these are my questions.

1 - can malicious users sniff packets sent and received by socket.io ? and if they can what should i do in order to stop this from happening.

2 - i need to know if i can disconnect a user from server if it is connected to a topic that it was not allowed

3 - i heard that rabbitmq is a good choice for implementing this system. i have read it's tutorials but i didn't quite get when should i use RMQ and when should i use socket.io. which on should i use for this project

4 - if i were to implement this using RMQ, again, i think i need to know how to prevent a user from connecting to a topic that it's not allowed

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use WSS for a secure WebSocket connection.
2. Yes, you can.
3. I don't get the point of why you need RMQ.
4. See number 3

I use a library named **FeathersJS** that has everything you need (IMO). FeathersJS as a client library as well to connect/perform action seamlessly with the server.

I have created a realtime react-native (android) using FeathersJS. Feathers have a concept of **channel** (room) where you can add or remove any connection.

> I am not sure if there is any decent WebSocket client for Java.